# ¿Como cargar Datos de un Javascript Solo al Seleccionar un valor de un Listboxt?

Tags: javascript, json

Necesito cargar los datos que se encuentran dentro de un Javascript, pero solo al seleccionar el valor de un listboxt, ya que si no es de esta forma, me dará un error en el sistema porque los datos dentro del javascript deben de ser filtrados mediante un parámetro. Ya tengo las Functions para filtrarlos, sin embargo no se como hacer que los datos dentro del javascript no se carguen automáticamente al cargar mi pagina. Creo que esto podría hacerse con JSON , pero no se como  pues no se mucho sobre su uso(solo lo he utilizado un poco para este proyecto de la universidad) Para pasar el parámetro usaría .change de JQuery, pero eso es lo de menos. Cualquier Información seria de gran ayuda, gracias.

Datos que necesito que se carguen al pasar un parámetro:

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instea
{
    dow: [ 1], // Monday

    <?php foreach($monday as $row){?>
       start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>',  // empty evalua si el campo se encuentra vaio o si es cero
    end: '<?php echo $row->hrs_ter ;?>' 
    <?php }?>
},
{
    dow: [2], // Tuesday
    <?php foreach($tuesday as $row1){?>
       start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row1->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>',   // 10am
    end: '<?php echo $row1->hrs_ter ;?>' // 4pm
    <?php }?>
},
{
    dow: [3], //  Wednesday
    <?php foreach($wednesday as $row2){?>
       start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row2->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>',  // 10am
    end: '<?php echo $row2->hrs_ter ;?>' // 4pm
    <?php }?>
},
{
    dow: [4], // Thursday
    <?php foreach($thursday as $row3){?>
       start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row3->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>',  // 10am
    end: '<?php echo $row3->hrs_ter ;?>' // 4pm
    <?php }?>
},
{
    dow: [5], // Friday
    <?php foreach($friday as $row4){?>
    start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row4->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>', 
    end: '<?php echo $row4->hrs_ter ;?>'// 4pm

    <?php }?>
},
{
    dow: [6], // Saturday

    <?php foreach($saturday as $row5){?>

    start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start_ok = $row5->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start_ok)) { echo $inicio;}
    else { echo $start_ok;} ?>', 
    end: '<?php echo $row5->hrs_ter ;?>'
     <?php }?>
}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno,te voy a dar una solución a tu problema 
Trata esto,

```js
function select(){
  var numeros = $('#numeros').val();
  
  alert(numeros);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numeros" id="numeros" onchange='select()'>
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
</select>
```

espero que te funcione trata de ejecutar el código antes de usarlo